# Open photos in a popup Jquery (Light Box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, lightbox

Folks,
I have a website template where i have a gallery. When i click on the image it opens in a new window although the template has a Jquery ( Lightbox ) which probably causes the photographs to come in a pop up. I am not able to use it owing to lack of technical know how. I tried a lot but am not getting any success. Can someone have a look and help me out.

[Here is the link to the files](https://drive.google.com/a/kashmiruniversity.ac.in/folderview?id=0B3LiYQz2D0Xndm5RZWsydE9CbTA&usp=sharing#)

Kindly open them in Visual Studio. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following link and make changes accordingly to your code,understand it and Implement.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/jquery-lightbox-image-slideshow-gallary.html